# Error linkeando servidores en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando linkear un servidor en sql server pero me sale el siguiente error.

SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "x.x.x.x" returned message "Client unable to establish connection". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893019)

Tengo por ejemplo los servers 1, 2 y 3, y me quiero linkear al servidor 3 desde el uno y el dos, pero en el servidor uno me arroja este error, mientras que en el dos me permite conectarme sin problema alguno.

Comment: ¿Que versión de windows y sqlserver usan los servidores?¿Firewall? ¿alguna diferencia notable de configuración entre el dos y el tres ?

Answer (score 0):

Por favor verifica que ambos servidores involucrados en el linked server soportan TLS 1.2. En [este enlace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server) muestra los números de build a partir del cual cada versión de SQL Server 2017 o versiones menores de SQL soportan TLS 1.2, por lo que se recomienda instalar los últimos service packs y/o cumulatives updates de las instancias SQL Server involucradas. SQL Server 2019 y 2022 soportan TLS 1.2 en todos sus builds. Observa que en el mismo documento que te comparto señala updates a nivel de sistema operativo que hay que aplicar también.